# Program: seems running old .pyc when i modify imported class file dynamically in the main program

Tags: python

I am trying to modify class runtime, which is imported in my main program and run time itself again. I am importing the same class, but this time it is running my old functionality (before class modification)

```
def mydef()
{
  from myclassfile import myclass
  ---------
  ---------
}

def mydef2()
{
  from myclassfile import myclass
  ---------
  ---------
  here, Modifying class by changing code in myclassfile 
}

def mydef3()
{
  from myclassfile import myclass
  ---------
  ---------
  getting old functionality [before modification of class] 
}
```

If I call class def in the following order:

```
mydef()
mydef2()
mydef3()
```

In mydef3() getting old functionality

I know I think its speed optimization part of python so it is preventing to again compile the same class and import it, but it should compile since class has been modified.

Please help me out?

Comment: What you wrote is not valid Python.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot verify this . Please check this: http://pastebin.com/7Gw0Y26u

Answer (score 1):

Within a single interpreter session, `import` only imports a module once, even if the source file has been modified. The module object is stored in the `sys.modules` dictionary on first import and all subsequent imports use that object. You can use `reload()` to reload a module, but modifying the source file is probably the hardest way to achieve what you want to do. If you post more information about your actual goal (i.e, *why* you think you need to modify a source file on disk and re-import it), someone will probably suggest a better way.

Comment: hey kindall can you send me piece of code how to reload the particular module i tried with reload(mymodule) so its throwing error : mymodule is not module type / object
how can i get module type of object for my particular module

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into subclassing `MyClass` instead of modifying it. Other code may be using `MyClass` and may not be aware of your modifications.

For example,

mymodule.py:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def do_something(self):
        return 'Foo'
```

modified.py:

```
from mymodule import MyClass


class ModifiedClass(MyClass):
    def do_something(self):
        original = super(ModifiedClass, self).do_something()
        return original * 2


def main():
    mycls = MyClass()
    modcls = ModifiedClass()

    print mycls.do_something()
    print modcls.do_something()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
$ python modified.py
Foo
FooFoo
```